# How to get array from API

Tags: php, arrays, api

I want to get the episode number and Released from
http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=the+walking+dead&season=6&r=json
but I don't know how to extract arrays from the api.

Can someone help me?

My code is:

```
$title = 'the+walking+dead';
$title2 = urlencode($title);
$json=file_get_contents("http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=$title2&season=6&r=json");
$details=json_decode($json);
if($details->Response=='True')
{   
        $episodios=$details->Episodes;
}
```

Comment: Add the language tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$title = 'the+walking+dead';
$title2 = urlencode($title);
$json = file_get_contents("http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=$title2&season=6&r=json");
$details = json_decode($json);
if ($details->Response == 'True') {

    echo 'There are ' . count($details->Episodes) . ' episodes<br />';

    foreach ($details->Episodes as $key => $episode) {
        echo 'Episode criteria number is ' . ($key + 1) . '<br />';
        echo 'Episode Number: ' . $episode->Episode . '<br />';
        echo 'Released: ' . $episode->Released . '<br />';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you and who i count the episodes of the season? To get the total?

Comment: `if ($details->Response == 'True') {
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($details->Episodes as $episode) {
        $i++;
        echo 'Episode Number: ' . $episode->Episode . '<br />';
        echo 'Released: ' . $episode->Released . '<br />';
    }
    echo $i;
}`

Comment: Just add a counter variable (such as `$i`), and in each iteration, add 1 to it, probably Matei will update answer with full code

Comment: @AdolfoRodrigues I've just updated my answer.. to count the episodes you simply use the `count()` function

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$title = 'the+walking+dead';
$title2 = urlencode($title);
$json=file_get_contents("http://www.omdbapi.com/t=$title2&season=6&r=json");
$details=json_decode($json);
if($details->Response=='True')
{   
    $episodios=$details->Episodes;
    foreach ($episodios as $episode) {
        echo 'Episode Number: ' . $episode->Episode . '<br />';
        echo 'Released Date: ' . $episode->Released . '<br />';
    }
}
?>
```